# Absolute position with Bootstrap and jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery and Bootstrap. On the first page load 2 divs are loaded, what is not the intention. Second thing, when I add a position-absolute to my div, my css does weird things and the container appears not in the centre anymore. I want to do this because now the slider flips and it needs to keep 1 place in the middle.
Could you please advise me on possible solutions?

I have a full page demo too: https://mella.ga/test/k/scherm.html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t2175dpa/

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue with the two divs being shown at the beginning you simply set display: none on your #slideshow with css, and with jQuery you show the #slideshow when document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideshow").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

For your second question I might need some more explanation to help, since I am not quite sure what you mean by "css does weird things". Could you explain this better? What do you want your container to do?

Comment: This is what happen with position absolute: https://monosnap.com/file/6Q3NpFUboumovHS2AfC1xJpwkyeatl